# RSPEC and PAPERCLIP gem for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip

I'm writing tests (RPSEC) and in a model for design uploads (which contain description, photo, and user_id)

Im using paperclip gem and all works great except for the tests because I dont know how to specify an image_tag..

My design_spec is as follows

```
describe Design do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

   before do
     @design = Design.new(description: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id, photo: ( THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP )
   end

   subject { @design }

   it { should respond_to(:description) }
   it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
   it { should have_attached_file(:photo) }
   it { should validate_attachment_presence(:photo) }

   it { should be_valid }

   describe "when user_id is not present" do
     before { @design.user_id = nil }

     it { should_not be_valid }
   end
 end
```

what i need help on is how to show that the design has a photo attachment. Obviously with description I canjust use a string, but thats not the case with an image.

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried taking a file stored locally on your HDD?

```
@design.photo = File.new("/path/to/my-image.png")
```

Comment: AGHHH YOUR AWEOSME!! that works perfectly i dont know why i didnt think of it lol the answers are always so clear when you see them

Comment: Also you can use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("me.jpg", "image/jpeg")` instead of `File.new` to create params like you'd get from submitting a form.

see: http://rdoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/UploadedFile